# ST_PointN to get Points from Geometry Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, gis, geospatial

I have a Shapefile from which I am extracting Geometry column and storing it into Table.
This is sample data stored in Geometry column which has 432 points.

> 0x000000000104AC010000AB3E57ABBBC4384127A08938705B57414F401361C3C43841C9E53F846C5B574190A0F8E1F6C438410F0BB5766E....

Now I want to extract each and Every point i.e. 432 points from the Geometry column and store it into another table. For that I am using `ST_PointN` column but it only gives me 1 point at a time. `ST_NumPoint` will give me 432 number but not all the points.

How do I extract each and every point from Geometry column and store it into DB?

Cheers,

Comment: I didn't quite get it. You want to read the points from a geometry and create one row for each point in another table. Is that it?

Comment: What is the problem with using ST_PointN?

Comment: The answer that I gave to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809201/storing-point-column-from-shapefile/12809687 "this question") will be helpful to you.

Comment: If i use ST_PointN it will give me one point at a time. How can I extract all the points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look in first example of ST_PointN documentation:
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_PointN.html
and pay attention to generate_series part.

It seems, your geometry is Linestring? Assuming, your geometry is in 'lines' table and you want to create 'points' table, something like that should work:

```
SELECT ST_PointN(a.the_geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(a.the_geom)))
INTO points
FROM lines a;
```

In case, your original geometry is polygon, you have to tweak that query little bit, because ST_PointN takes linestrings as parameter:

```
SELECT ST_PointN(
    ST_ExteriorRing(a.the_geom), 
    generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(a.the_geom) - 1)
)
INTO points
FROM lines a;
```

First and last point will be same in ExteriorRing of polygon. It's up to your needs, whether you use `ST_NPoints(a.the_geom) - 1` or `ST_NPoints(a.the_geom)`. In first case, first point will be present also as last point.

Comment: Thanks for this. But it seems that I can't run this query on SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry! My mistake, I didn't notice you answered about SQL Server, that example works with PostgreSQL.